# railsで画像の表示に制限をつける方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`public/images/private_photo/**.jpg`これらの画像をログインしているユーザーのみにアクセスを許可するにはどうしたら良いのでしょうか。

表示の切り替えだけであればview側で可能ですが、直接リンクへアクセスすると表示ができてしまいます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ログインユーザー向けのコンテンツ表示についてはサービス的には比較的実施検討が多い技術かと思います。

上記でも回答ありましたバイナリを返す方法がアプリ内でクローズする事が出来、最も実装はしやすいのですが、サーバの負荷が上がってきたときなどに大規模サービスの時には運用面で厳しいこともあります。

規模が大きいサービスのようであればインフラ含めた検討として、「nginxのsecure_link」や「cloudfrontの署名付きURL」など検討してみては如何でしょうか？

サービスの規模に応じて検討くださいませ。

Answer (score 1):

おそらく安直でお手軽なのが 
PrivateContentController#image みたいなのを作って、
その中で認証処理を終えてから
send_dataでcontent-typeなど設定してバイナリを返す方法です。

このやり方は、DBにコンテンツを格納した場合も同様です。
（データの置かれている場所がデータベースなのかファイルなのかの違いでしかありません）

send_dataについては、こちらを確認してください。
http://railsdoc.com/references/send_data

ご承知とは思いますが。
ディレクトリトラバーサルなどが起きないよう設計には気をつけてください。